# case-insensitive predicates java

Tags: java, predicate, specifications

I don’t quite understand how I need to make the field that needs to be compared from the query be case-insensitive

```java
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getEmitentName())) {
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(registry.get("emitentName"), request.getEmitentName()));
}
```

Comment: Make both uppercase or both lowercase (like `registry.get(emitentName).toUpperCase())`)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thx for answer, can you write how to do it, cause I already tried to do that

Comment: Oh, wait, I didn't notice the criteria builder. It's a bit different then. Let me freshen up my memory on how those works and (if no-one else answered) I'll get back to you

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ok I will wait, thank you

Comment: Do never "normalise" by using `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` when you have to deal with any other language than English. There is a reason why `String::equalsIgnoreCase` and `String::compareToIgnoreCase` exists. Play around with words like "Straße" or Locales like the Turkish to see what I mean.

Comment: @tquadrat ok, I won't leave it unnoticed